# Why does the max function only work with numbers 0 - 9 and how can i change this?

Tags: python, sorting, max

This following line is sorting out a text line in the style of

```
Richard 4 2 10
```

Yet when i use the following code it doesn't pick 10 as the highest. Is there a way to extend the range of the max function?

```
max_score = max(map(int, row[1:]))
```

The rest of my code is

```
with open (file, 'r') as f:
          for line in f:
               row = line.split()
               if not row:# bypasses list indec out of range
                   continue
               name = row[0]
               max_score = max(map(int, line.split()[1:]))
```

The expected output would be

```
Richard 10
```

Comment: I would actually expect a `ValueError` on `int('i')` from your code - could you provide an actual [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you please show us what output you get instead then? Because `max(map(int, line.split()[1:]))` will produce `10` for the line you gave.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `split` to create a list of tokens using whitespace as the delimiter. You are current using the `str` directly in your `map`, which will try to convert *each character* to `int`

```
>>> s = 'Richard 4 2 10'
>>> max(map(int, s.split()[1:]))
10
```

Comment: This doesn't do it i will update the question above so you can see the rest of my code

Comment: @dfsfsdfdsfs: then in future produce a minimal verifiable sample *from the outset*, including expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your digits to `int` ,So you can use a list comprehension within `max` and use `int` function :

```
>>> max([int(i) for i in s.split()[1:]])
10
```

some bench-marking :

```
~$ python -m timeit "s = 'Richard 4 2 10';max(int(i) for i in s.split()[1:])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "s = 'Richard 4 2 10';max([int(i) for i in s.split()[1:]])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "s = 'Richard 4 2 10';max(map(int, s.split()[1:]))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 usec per loop
```

after your edit :

```
>>> l=s.split()
>>> l[0] +' '+str(max([int(i) for i in l[1:]]))
'Richard 10'
```

Comment: I think a list comprehension would be faster ... or map (+1 all the same)

Comment: `sorted()` is an O(NlogN) option; it shouldn't be here at all when you already have a O(N) solution (`max()`).

Comment: Yeah! i though for this case that list is small it doesn't make much difference , but its not like so!

Comment: What does the i in the brackets mean

Comment: @dfsfsdfdsfs its a temp container for items in list, when you loop over it